# DateTime.Now in KQL

Tags: search, metadata, display-template, fast-search, kql

In SP 2013 on-prem, I am using display template and a list to show alerts on the front page of the intranet. I want the alerts to be showed from the list when the list item has a start date that is less than or equal to today, and end date that is greater than or equal to today.

This is my query, where Date01 is start date, and date02 is end date:

```
path:{Site.URL}  ContentTypeId:0x0100277BL3829BB9VIC110PXT410125FCC83* Date01<={Today}  Date02>={Today}
```

My query works, but the only issue is that Date02 is of type Date and Time, and KQL query does not care about time. I want {Today} to behave like DateTime.Now, while it behaves like Date.Now

How can I do that ?
Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

With KQL it is only possible to query by day ranges. If you want to use something like DateTime.Now you will have to use FQL instead, see [link](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/limiting-search-results-by-exact-time.html)

Comment: Can FQL be used in content search web part?

Comment: Only via injecting it as a refinement filter. Doable with javascript, but require some fiddling.

Comment: That sounds a bit complicated :).  I ended up running the logical part of scheduling as javascript statements in the Display templates.

Comment: you can pass the current date to the KQL as a querystring parameter from javascript  with document.location; the drawback of this workaround is the page gets refreshed on some (older) browsers

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I used `now()` which returns the current date/time as DateTime object.